# swift recursive function that prints the binary representation of an integer

Tags: swift, function, recursion, binary

I was wondering what would a recursive function that prints the binary representation of the integer would look like in the swift?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible implementation:

```
func toBinary(_ n: Int) -> String {
    if n < 2 {
        return "\(n)"
    }

    return toBinary(n / 2) + "\(n % 2)"
}

print(toBinary(11))  // "1011"
print(toBinary(170)) // "10101010"
```

Note: This doesn't handle negative integers.

---

If you actually want the function to print the binary instead of returning it as a `String`, you can do this:

```
func printBinary(_ n: Int, terminator: String = "\n") {
    if n < 2 {
        print(n, terminator: terminator)
    }
    else {
        printBinary(n / 2, terminator: "")
        print(n % 2, terminator: terminator)
    }
}

printBinary(11)
printBinary(170)

printBinary(23, terminator: "")
print(" is the representation of 23 in binary")
```

Output:

> ```
> 1011
> 10101010
> 10111 is the representation of 23 in binary
> ```